# Не получается сделать выбор файла

Tags: 1с

Постоянно выходит одна и та же ошибка:

```
{ВнешняяОбработка.ЗагрузкаПриобретенияИзЭксель.Форма.Форма.Форма(36,35)}:
Тип не определен (ФормаВыбораФайла)
    ДиалогВыбораФайла = Новый <<?>>ФормаВыбораФайла(РежимДиалогаВыбораФайла.Открытие); (Проверка: Сервер) {ВнешняяОбработка.ЗагрузкаПриобретенияИзЭксель.Форма.Форма.Форма(25,20)}: Переменная не определена (ИмяФайла)
    Если ПустаяСтрока(<<?>>ИмяФайла) Тогда (Проверка: Тонкий клиент) {ВнешняяОбработка.ЗагрузкаПриобретенияИзЭксель.Форма.Форма.Форма(28,20)}: Переменная не определена (ИмяФайла)
    Файл = Новый Файл(<<?>>ИмяФайла.Открытие); (Проверка: Тонкий клиент)
```

Я и на клиенте и на сервере ставлю, и без результатно.

Привожу полный текст модуля:

```
#Область ВыборФайлаЗагрузки

&НаКлиенте
Процедура ИмяФайлаОткрытие(Элемент,СтандартнаяОбработка)
    ЗапуститьПриложение("explorer " + Элемент.Значение);
    СтандартнаяОбработка = ЛОЖЬ;
    
КонецПроцедуры

      
Процедура ИмяФайлаНачалоВыбора(Элемент, СтандартнаяОбработка)
    ВыборФайла(Элемент, Истина, , Ложь, Истина);
КонецПроцедуры

 &НаКлиенте
Процедура ИмяФайлаПриИзменении(Элемент)
    Если ПустаяСтрока(ИмяФайла) Тогда
        Возврат;
    КонецЕсли;  
    Файл = Новый Файл(ИмяФайла.Открытие);
    Если Не Файл.Существует() Тогда
        Возврат; 
    КонецЕсли;
КонецПроцедуры

Процедура ВыборФайла(Элемент, ПроверятьСуществование=Ложь,
    Знач РасширениеПоУмолчанию = "xml",АрхивироватьФайлДанных = Истина, ВыборФайлаПравил = Ложь)    
    ДиалогВыбораФайла                               =   Новый ФормаВыбораФайла(РежимДиалогаВыбораФайла.Открытие);
    ФормаВыбораФайла.Фильтр                     =   "Документ XML (*.xml)|*.xml|";
    ФормаВыбораФайла.Расширение                 =   "xml";
    ФормаВыбораФайла.Заголовок                      =   "Выберите файл";
    ФормаВыбораФайла.ПредварительныйПросмотр        =   Ложь;
    ФормаВыбораФайла.ИндексФильтра                  =   0;
    ФормаВыбораФайла.ПолноеИмяФайла             =   Элемент.Значение;
    ФормаВыбораФайла.ПроверятьСуществованиеФайла    =   ПроверятьСуществование; 
    Если ФормаВыбораФайла.Выбрать() Тогда
        Элемент.Значение = ФормаВыбораФайла.ПолноеИмяФайла;
        ИмяФайлаПриИзменении(Элемент);      
        
    КонецЕсли; 
    
    
КонецПроцедуры
  
    &НаКлиенте
Процедура ОбработатьНачалоВыбораФайла(СтандартнаяОбработка)
    
    СтандартнаяОбработка = Ложь;
    РежимДиалога = РежимДиалогаВыбораФайла.Открытие;
    ДиалогВыбораФайла = Новый ДиалогВыбораФайла(РежимДиалога);
    ДиалогВыбораФайла.ПроверятьСуществованиеФайла = Истина;
    ДиалогВыбораФайла.МножественныйВыбор = Ложь;
    ДиалогВыбораФайла.Заголовок = Нстр("ru = 'Задайте имя файла загрузки'");
    ДиалогВыбораФайла.ПолноеИмяФайла = ИмяФайлаЗагрузки;
    
    ДиалогВыбораФайла.Фильтр = "Лист Excel 2007-...(*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|Лист Excel (*.xls)|*.xls";;
    Если ДиалогВыбораФайла.Выбрать() Тогда
        ИмяФайлаЗагрузки = ДиалогВыбораФайла.ПолноеИмяФайла;
    КонецЕсли;
    
КонецПроцедуры


#КонецОбласти
```

Comment: Вам нужно сделать диалог выбора файла?!

Comment: Как у вас объявлена переменная "ИмяФайла"? Это реквизит формы?